# How to configure proxy settings for Java?

Tags: java, url, proxy

I am trying to open a URL and read the website line by line.  I can do this fine in Eclipse because I guess Eclipse configures it automatically for you.  When I try to run the program from the command line the program hangs and never reads the URL.

After some research the problem has to do with the proxy settings, I figured out.  All articles I come across say to change something like this:

```java
System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies","true");
```

Or to add lines of code like this:

```java
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "webcache.mydomain.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");
```

But I have no idea what to put for my proxy settings and what any of those `System.setProperty` calls do.  Does anyone know how to set the proxy settings?  I am just trying to run this from my home computer on a localhost and I'm not even behind a proxy or anything.

Here is the code I use that works fine in Eclipse.

```java
URL link = new URL("http://www.yahoo.com");
            
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(link.openStream()));
//InputStream in = link.openStream();
String inputLine = "";
int count = 0;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    site = site + "\n" + inputLine;
}
in.close();
```

Comment: What happens when you run it from command-line ? Do you get any error ? Can you show the error stack trace ?

Comment: Are you sure that your application is not blocked by the proxy of your OS (especially if you are using XP) ?

Comment: +1 to firewall or antivirus problem. There's no need to set proxy if your network don't have one.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7.  How can I tell if it's blocked by the proxy of my OS.If I run a "ping www.yahoo.com" it returns a reply from 67.195.160.76 and says 4 packs sent, 4 received and none lost.  Not sure if that helps.

Comment: No error happens, the program just starts, then it just hangs forever trying to access the URL.

Comment: Add logging to see where things hang.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the problem. Removed my answer.

Comment: Try turning off Windows firewall to see if it helps. If it does, then you need to add your program as an exception to the firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sun (er, Oracle) [Java SE 6 Java Networking and Proxies](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) page covers these properties.

Answer (score 1):

`java -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhostURL

     -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPortNumber

     -Dhttp.proxyUser=someUserName

     -Dhttp.proxyPassword=somePassword javaClassToRun`